# how to create a virtual machine in hyper-v server 2008 r2

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-machines, windows-7

I've installed server 2008 r2 core and the only installed role is Hyper-V. i want to install a virtual machine like windows xp on server and manage it from windows 7 installed on my laptop. management console installed successfully in windows 7 but i cannot see any option in management console to add virtual machines.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider learning a little bit about remote server administration before jumping straight into Server Core and Hyper-V.

Answer (score 1):

In the Hyper-V Manager, right click in the left tree, connect to server, enter the IP or name of the Server you installed. Click on that server in the left tree, in the right pane you'll see the "New" option.

Answer (score 0):

In the Hyper-V Manager, the "New" button is in the top right of the pane.  Click it.  Then you'll get choices: virtual machine, hard disk and floppy disk.

Answer (score -1):

Server Core has no UI - so you need a Windows 7 machine (or another server) and to set up the management tools on that. Then you can crate the virtual machine there.

Alternatively - use PowerShell to script the creation, but it is a lot less convenient.